# SQL SELECT using a session variable

Tags: php, sql, select

```
Require("dbconnect.php");//works is used on other another page


echo $Customer_id;//Displays correctly
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: turn on error reporting in PHP and add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` after the connection, so you'll know whats up

Comment: Didn't read question properly before answering sorry! Does `$Customer_id` print *before* you do the db connection?

Comment: what is the datatype of customer id  is it integer or string

Comment: Removed salutation: "Thanks in advance", don't do it next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Check that use session variable is getting the data or not.
If the Customer id is of varchar then you are missing single inverted comma in where clause.

```
session_start();
$Customer_id = $_SESSION['id'];

Require("dbconnect.php");//works is used on other another page
$sql = "SELECT Job_id FROM Job";
$sql.= " WHERE Job_Customer_id = '$Customer_id'";
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$Job_id = $row['Job_id'];

echo $Customer_id;//Displays correctly 
echo $Job_id;//Curently dose not display anything
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `$sql.=` line to this:

```
$sql.= " WHERE Job_Customer_id = '$Customer_id'"
```

with the `'` around `$Customer_id`.